# Adding a value at the end of this Filter formula Google Sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have the below formula to remove blanks in a list and would like to add a separate cell value at the end of it (let's call it A1), not related to range V9:V22, but I would like A1 to show up below the list this formula creates:

=filter(V9:V22,V9:V22<>"")

Any quick add on to connect A1 to the end of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to add a value to a simuliar formula? I'm using Google Sheets and Filter works.

Comment: Not using Excel, formula works fine....just need to put A1 at the end as a label.

Answer (score 1):

That was an obvious fix, I just extended the range and made the last value in the filter what I needed.I put A1 at the end of range V9:V22.